# Azure SDK for Java - how to fetch network security group state?

Tags: java, azure

I'm new to the Azure SDK.

I could fetch NetworkSecurityGroup Name, Location & Label parameters, but Active/Inactive state is missing there.

```
Configuration config = ManagementConfiguration.configure(new URI(uri),subscriptionId, keyStoreLocation, keyStorePassword, KeyStoreType.jks);

NetworkManagementClient networkManagementClient = NetworkManagementService.create(config);

NetworkSecurityGroupOperations NSGOps = networkManagementClient.getNetworkSecurityGroupsOperations();
NetworkSecurityGroupListResponse nsgResp = NSGOps.list();

ArrayList<NetworkSecurityGroup> nsgList = nsgResp.getNetworkSecurityGroups();

for( int i=0; i < nsgList.size();++i) {
  NetworkSecurityGroup nsg = nsgList.get(i);
  System.out.print( nsg.getName() );
  System.out.print( nsg.getLocation() );
  //System.out.println( nsg.getState( "IS MISSING!! :(") );
...
```

Are there any alternate API?

I can see State parameter exist in REST API documented https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn913821.aspx, but the same is not implemented in SDK??

Comment: I suggest  to use the REST API to get the state property of NetworkSecurityGroup. Besides, you can find the Class NetworkSecurityGroupForAssociationResponse in the azure-svc-mgmt-network-0.8.0(+) http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-svc-mgmt-network/0.8.0 (Note: the azure-management-network jar was renamed to azure-svc-mgmt-network since version 0.8). It has the state property for Network Interface. Is this state your needs?

Comment: I'm looking for state property of NetworkSecurityGroup, not the NetworkInterface.

Comment: I checked all version of Azure Management Network SDK, the Class NSG has no the state property. So I think you can only get it via the response of the REST API for the present.

Comment: Microsoft has recently published SDK for managing Network Security Groups using Java SDK APIs. All of those source files are available on git-hub repository. For sample you can refer:
[NSG Manager](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/azure-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/network/samples/ManageNetworkSecurityGroup.java)